# Bind the content to the outline in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I created a rectangle into Illustrator CC and I putted inside it a print in a right position.
I would to move that rectangle but the print moves.
Is it possible to bind the print to the rectangle's outline?

Comment: Are you using clipping mask?

Comment: yes, I am using clipping mask

Answer (score 1):

When you use move dialog, check or uncheck "Transform Patterns" to suit your need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select both and group them. You can move them together regardless have you dragged the text or the rectangle.